# populate a drop down in php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have a mysql database of games that you can hire. I created a query in php so that the user is able to type in a title or game description and the result will be shown in a table as a simple list. However, I want to display the results of my array in a drop down. But how?  I've tried to apply code snippets I've found online(including Stack Overflow) but failed miserably to make them work. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Game ID</td>
        <td>Game Name</td>
        <td>Game Description</td>
    </tr>
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
        $search=$_POST['search'];
        $sql="SELECT* FROM gamestbl WHERE game_name LIKE '%{$search}%' OR game_description LIKE '%{$search}%'";
        $q=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $res['game_id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['game_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['game_description'];?></td>
</tr>
    <?php }
}?>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by drop down? a select element in a form?

Comment: use <select><option> instead of table

Comment: @ Micheal Coleman Yes, eventually, I want the user to select the game name and then insert a row in my booking table in mysql

Comment: @JeanGkol I have tried to write various statements using <select><option> but failed miserably to make it work. Apologies I'm quite the beginner here

Comment: I'm beginner too. now see the answers others give you, perhaps it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem, and you've got the right idea. Right now, you're populating these into a `<table>` element's `<tr>` and `<td>` elements. So, why not change that to a `<select>` and `<option>` layout?

Here's the basic idea. During your while loop, echo an `<option>` for each game. Set the `value` attribute to the game's id and it's display to the game's name and description.:

```
<option value="<?php echo $res["game_id"]; ?>"><?php $res["game_name"]."-".$res["game_description"]; ?></option>
```

Like you have with your `<table>`, make sure to define the `<select>` outside of the php `while` loop, or you'll end up with multiple dropdowns.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain how to implement the solution. That kind of patience is what really helps newbies like me progress

Comment: No problem! I was in your shoes once. I find that it's better to explain an answer to someone rather than just do it for them; you learn better that way :P

Answer (score 2):

Replace your table with select:

```
<select name="game">
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
        $search=$_POST['search'];
        $sql="SELECT* FROM gamestbl WHERE game_name LIKE '%{$search}%' OR game_description LIKE '%{$search}%'";
        $q=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $res['game_id'];?>"><?php echo $res['game_name'];?></option>
    <?php }
}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Tikashi Thank you, I think I would have struggled to get the syntax right here so your code is really helpful.